# Webpack Config Plugin: compiler.options.resolve is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am trying to get `webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` to work, which presents me with the following error:

```
node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:4499
                        if (module.buildInfo.assets) {
                                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'assets')
```

I couldn't find any solution, so I was thinking of building something myself and looked at  [`module-replace-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/nerdchacha/module-replace-webpack-plugin/blob/master/src/index.js) for inspiration. This plugin apparently accesses `compiler.options.resolve` for it's work. I looked at it during the compile process via `plugins: [ {apply: (compiler) => { console.log(compiler.options.resolve); }]`. It turns out resolve is undefined.

Why would compiler.options.resolve be undefined and how do I make it being defined?

Note: my source code is in TypeScript.

Comment: Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example